# findOneAndUpdate with push array elements gives error in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My query is as shown below:

```
const updateLikes = (item_id, userInfo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        itemLike.findOneAndUpdate({ 'item_id': item_id }, { $inc: { no_of_likes: 1 } }, { "$push": { "users": userInfo } }, { 'new': true }, (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (info) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject('no item found');
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

itemLike.js

```
const itemLike = new Schema({
    item_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'items', index: true },
    no_of_likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }]
}, { versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('item_like', itemLike);
```

As soon as I execute this query , I get the error as shown below:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\uName\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3702:16)
    at C:\Users\uName\api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:273:21
    at C:\Users\uName\api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The docs for [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) shows that you're providing one too many parameters. It should be `conditions, update, options, callback`.

You're getting an error because Mongoose is trying to invoke `{ 'new': true }` as the callback function. It looks like your update definition has been split into two objects by mistake.

You need to remove the braces highlighted in bold below.

> { $inc: { no_of_likes: 1 } **}**, **{** "$push": { "users": userInfo } }

For completeness, your final update definition should like this:

```
{ $inc: { no_of_likes: 1 }, "$push": { "users": userInfo } }
```

Answer (score 7):

The above comment is correct but misleading (it makes it look like the error is the fix), this is the correct syntax :

`{ $inc: { no_of_likes: 1 } , "$push": { "users": userInfo } }`