# MongoDB concurrency when wirting to same array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency

I have been reading about mongodb concurrency but to be honest I still don't get how things work in mongodb. In my use case for example I have a document holding the array of the user followers

```
const userFollowing = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userID : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        followingProfiles: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            default: [],
            ref: 'Profile'
        }]
    }
)
```

So let's assume the following happens two different users decide to follow the same user so I'm confused what would happen based on my code but here is what I do:

1-I read the following document of the user

2-I push the new reference in the array

3- Save the document again.

```
//Get the user following list by Id
        const userFollowings = await UserFollowing.findOne({
            userID: req.user._id
        })


        const userProfile = await Profile.findOne({
            user: req.user._id
        })

     
        userFollowings.followingProfiles.push(profileID)
        await userFollowings.save()
```

**My Question**: If the two users read the same instance of the document which let's say had 3 following and each one would add a new reference to the following array. The expected output is that the array after the concurrent writes would contain 5 indexes but I' scared that .save() overwites the entire document which would then make the later write only exist.

Comment: Generally, you want to _update_ the collection's document based upon a condition. - as a single operation . There is a `$push` array update operator as shown in this post: [findOneAndUpdate with push array elements...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682653/findoneandupdate-with-push-array-elements-gives-error-in-mongoose).

Comment: Use $push as previous comment says.